# KeyboardEvent.key not supported in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-events, keycode

I was building a simple app that would help me easily get keyCodes/charCodes for all keys. When you press a key, it displays the keyCode/charCode on the screen, and below it's supposed to display the name of the actual key that is pressed.

In Firefox, the `KeyboardEvent` object has the `key` property that holds the name of the key that is pressed (e.g if I press "F", the `keyCode` is 102, but the `key` is "f"), but unfortunately I couldn't find it in Chrome.

Is there a workaround for this issue, and if not, does someone have data about all they keycodes and their corresponding key names?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Hello, in FF and Ch "F" keyCode is 70

Answer (score 0):

There is a [polyfill/shim for KeyboardEvent](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

You should post some sample code to better illustrate what you're trying to do; but as I understand it, you have the charcode and you need the key.  [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) will return the character (key) value from the given code.  For the converse, you could use [String.prototype.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).